# Adding image to table given link

Tags: javascript, html, image, html-table

I have the following code which goes through my rows and columns

```
           for (var j=0; j < cols; j++) {
            for (var k=0; k < cols; k++) {
              alert(data[j][i])
              if(data[j][i].endsWith(".jpg"))
              {
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = data[j][i];
                img.onload = function() { //check to make sure that the 
                  tableData += '<td>' + img + '</td>';
                };
              }
              else
              {
                tableData += '<td>'+data[j][i]+'</td>'; 
              }
              break;
            }
          }
```

I am trying to create images but nothing pops up in that spot. Any idea what I might be doing wrong? I also tried it without the .onload and this pops up [object HTMLImageElement]

Comment: Several things about that code don't make sense. What is `tableData`?
 Concatenating a reference to an `img` element into the `tableData` string makes no sense. And the `.onload` function would run *later*, after the image loads, your code doesn't stop and wait for it.

Comment: Solved thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

- variable `img` hold object, not `HTML` string. Use `<img>` tag as `string` instead!
- Also note that `onload` event is async, callback could invoke later!

```js
for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
  for (var k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
    alert(data[j][i])
    if (data[j][i].endsWith(".jpg")) {
      var img = '<img src="' + data[j][i] + '">';
      tableData += '<td>' + img + '</td>';
    } else {
      tableData += '<td>' + data[j][i] + '</td>';
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating `k` in your second loop but you are calling `data[j][i]`. I guess you need to call

```
data[j][k]
```

And if the first loop cycles through the columns the second loop should go through the rows unless rows and columns are equal.

```
for (var k=0; k < rows; k++) {
```